# Problema con función de Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

model:

```
    package com.example.webs.model;
    
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
    import jakarta.persistence.*;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "empleado")
    public class Empleado {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long idemple;
        private String nombre;
        private String apellido;
        private Date fecha_naci;
        private String genero;
        
        
        public Empleado() {
            
        }
        public Empleado(Long idemple, String nombre, String apellido, Date fecha_naci, String genero) {
            super();
            this.idemple = idemple;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.fecha_naci = fecha_naci;
            this.genero = genero;
            
        }
        
        public Long getIdemple() {
            return idemple;
        }
        public void setIdemple(Long idemple) {
            this.idemple = idemple;
        }
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
        public String getApellido() {
            return apellido;
        }
        public void setApellido(String apellido) {
            this.apellido = apellido;
        }
        
        public Date getFecha_naci() {
            return fecha_naci;
        }
        public void setFecha_naci(Date fecha_naci) {
            this.fecha_naci = fecha_naci;
        }
        public String getGenero() {
            return genero;
        }
        public void setGenero(String genero) {
            this.genero = genero;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Empleado [idemple=" + idemple + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", fecha_naci="
                    + fecha_naci + ", genero=" + genero + "]";
        }
        
        

}
```

lo que me arroja al ejecutar:

```
 Hibernate: 
    create table empleado (
        idemple number(19,0) generated as identity,
        apellido varchar2(255 char),
        fecha_naci timestamp(6),
        genero varchar2(255 char),
        nombre varchar2(255 char),
        primary key (idemple)
    )
    
    
  lo que me arroja la ejecucion:

    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.301-05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table empleado (
        idemple number(19,0) generated as identity,
        apellido varchar2(255 char),
        fecha_naci timestamp(6),
        genero varchar2(255 char),
        nombre varchar2(255 char),
        primary key (idemple)
    )" via JDBC [ORA-02000: falta la palabra clave ALWAYS

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-02000/]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table empleado (
        idemple number(19,0) generated as identity,
        apellido varchar2(255 char),
        fecha_naci timestamp(6),
        genero varchar2(255 char),
        nombre varchar2(255 char),
        primary key (idemple)
    )" via JDBC [ORA-02000: falta la palabra clave ALWAYS

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-02000/]

[2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.301-05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table empleado (
        idemple number(19,0) generated as identity,
        apellido varchar2(255 char),
        fecha_naci timestamp(6),
        genero varchar2(255 char),
        nombre varchar2(255 char),
        primary key (idemple)
    )" via JDBC [ORA-02000: falta la palabra clave ALWAYS

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-02000/]
```

EL ERROR QUE SALE:

at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:574) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at

```
org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~

[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at
```

org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    
    
    
        at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]


        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at com.example.webs.WebsApplication.main(WebsApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02000: falta la palabra clave ALWAYS
    
    https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-02000/
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:702) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:608) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1330) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:1102) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:456) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:498) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:190) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1368) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1958) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1594) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:2636) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:2585) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:334) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
    Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02000: falta la palabra clave ALWAYS
    
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:710) ~[ojdbc11.jar:23.3.0.23.09]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
    
    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.313-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.360-05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.519-05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.609-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.635-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.648-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.webs.WebsApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started WebsApplication in 2.196 seconds (process running for 2214.55)
    [2m2024-03-08T17:54:02.653-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Condition evaluation unchanged
    [2m2024-03-08T17:56:16.882-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    [2m2024-03-08T17:56:16.883-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    [2m2024-03-08T17:56:16.885-05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9916[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio, mira a ver si te sirve esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806412/sql-error-ora-02000-missing-always-keyword-when-create-identity-column-based-t

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en ejecución te bota este error"ORA-02000: falta la palabra clave ALWAYS", probablemente se lanza esto porque estas tratando de conectarte a un oracle 12c y el cliente que tienes instalado localmente no soporta esa característica, por lo cual te recomiendo revises la versión de tu cliente oracle, este debería ser 11g o menor